# go button on iphone textpad

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios

how do i capture the event raised when the go button on a textpad with go:

this.password.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Go;

cheers

w://

cross posting from: http://forums.monotouch.net/yaf_postst467_go-button-on-textpad.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this is just wrapping the Cocoa Touch methods for a UITextField.

If you were using a UITextField directly, you'd give it a delegate object and implement textFieldShouldReturn: in the delegate.  That method would be called whenever the user taps the return key, regardless of how that key is labeled.

Presumably Monotouch has something similar...

Comment: Yeah, the UITextFieldDelegate class in MonoTouch has that one method: 
'bool ShouldReturn (UITextField textField)'.
All the methods are available in the MT Rosetta stone: http://tirania.org/tmp/rosetta.html

Answer (score 1):

There is an event fired in Xamarin.iOS, it's called ShouldReturn.

```
text.ShouldReturn = (UITextField textField) => {
   Example();
   return true;
};
```